# Prove that $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}$ $\geq$ $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}$

Tags: inequality, summation, geometric-inequalities, sum-of-squares-method

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle and $a+b+c=3$

Prove that:

$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a} \geq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

**My Attempt**

I think this inequality could be proved using the A.M. - G.M. however, I am not sure if I am correct or not. I request someone to please post the solution for the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Please help me find the solution to this problem ...

Comment: Set $a=x+y,b=y+z,c=x+z$, then the condition becomes: $x+y+z=\dfrac{3}{2}$ and $x,y,z>0$

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the idea. I request you to please clarify ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2c\geq\sum_{cyc}ab$$ or
$$3\sum_{cyc}a^2c\geq\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}a$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2c-a^2b-abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^2c-2a^2b-2abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2abc)\geq3\sum_{cyc}(a^2b-a^2c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}(b-a)^3$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+c-b)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Its a duplicate (found instantly on Approach0) and you answered an identical question before.